# DXErrorProvider Duvidas na utilização

Tags: c#, validação, devexpress

Como vai?

Estou começando a utilizar os componentes do DevExpress, e gostaria de implementar o DXerrorProvider, que no meu caso, se o valor do text box for nulo, ou vazio, seria apresentado o ícone de erro ao lado.

Então entrei no help do DevExpress: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraEditorsDXErrorProviderErrorTypeEnumtopic

Não estou entendendo o código em si, pelo que entendi o bindingSource faz a ligação entre meu textbox e a minha fonte de dados, que nesse caso é vazia.

logo em seguida atribuo essa ligação ao DXerrorProvider, certo?

depois vem uma classe myrecord, para que serve? seria para quando colocar o mouse em cima aparecer a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Pessoal, consegui colocar para rodar, estava usando o form do visual studio, quando criei um form em branco do DevExpress, rodou.. porem ainda estou tentando entender por completo o codigo. Valeu